# Событие onClick();

Tags: javascript, extjs

Доброго времени суток!
Работаю на `ext js 4.2`.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии какого-то `button-а`, открывалось новое окно?
Ну, типа, `btnCreate.onClick(windows.show())`.

Вот `window` который я создал

```
 var crtWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window')
```

Что писать?

```
handler: function () 
      {
       crtWindow.show();
        }
```

Comment: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.button.Button

Comment: ExtJs - библиотека в классичесокм ооп стиле. Вам нужно Создать экземлпяр ext.button.Button, повесить ему handler. Смотрите в доках, доки охренненые, там все описано.

Comment: у меня есть экземпляр `button`. Что писать в `handler`?

Comment: @Утка я обновил вопрос

Comment: я решил. Теперь другая проблема. При нажатие `x` на окне, оно закрывается. а при обратном клике на `button` окно не вызывается. как исправить?

Comment: Залезть в доки по ext.window.Window и внимательно прочитать доки нажатия по крестику. Это флаг closable, в описании говорится что компонент при закрытии дестроится целиком, его надо заново создать. В доках по эксту есть ответы на 99% таких вопросов, надо просто научиться их читать